# Finding the sum of a list created by a user

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, user-input, datalistitem

I am having trouble getting the sum of the list inputted by the user, I have tried multiple ways, I just need help in what I can do to the sum of the list. Thanks, for any help.

```
import statistics
data=[]
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number (type quit to leave): ")
    data.append(num)
    if num == "quit":
        data.remove("quit")
        break
def Average(data):
    return sum(data) / len(data)

print(*data, sep=", ")
data.sort()
print("The max value entered is: ", max(data))
print("The min value entered is: ", min(data))
print("Sorted list: ", data)
print("First and Last removed: ", (data[1:-1]))
print("The List average is: ", sum(data))
```

Comment: hint: you need the list to contain integers in order to sum it

Comment: @DeepSpace how do I do that if I need my exit to be a str "quit"

Comment: Perhaps you can check the input *before* adding it to the list?

Comment: @DeepSpace How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

```
data=[]
while True:
   num = input("Enter a number (type quit to leave): ")
   data.append(num)
   if num == "quit":
       data.remove("quit")
       break
for i in range(0, len(data)):
   data[i] = int(data[i])

print(*data, sep=", ")
data.sort()
print("The max value entered is: ", max(data))
print("The min value entered is: ", min(data))
print("Sorted list: ", data)
print("First and Last removed: ", (data[1:-1]))
print("The List average is: ", sum(data))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).